# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} = \frac{-x}{2}$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} = \frac{-x}{2}$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

I rewrote to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n(x+\pi))}{n}$, but then I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.